# Display name for nested complex type

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

i have two model class like below,

i want to use different labels for Categoy.Name property if its nested,but if i use complex type,it didnt bind to name property,is there any options something like BindTo("Category.Name") for complex types???

```
  public class ProductModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Product Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Category Name")]
        [BindTo("Category.Name")]
        public CategoryModel Category { get; set; }
    }

    public class CategoryModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use the [MetadataType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.metadatatypeattribute.aspx) attribute.

```
public class ProductModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Product Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public CategoryPropertyModel Category { get; set; }
}

[MetadataType(typeof(ICategoryModelCategoryDisplay))
public class CategoryModel : CategoryBaseModel { }

[MetadataType(typeof(ICategoryModelDisplay))
public class CategoryPropertyModel : CategoryBaseModel { }

public class CategoryBaseModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public interface ICategoryModelSimpleDisplay  
{
    [DisplayName("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public interface ICategoryModelCategoryDisplay  
{
    [DisplayName("Category Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

When you use `CategoryModel` the display name will be `Name`.

When you use `CategoryPropertyModel` the display name will be `Category Name`.