# DisplayName Attribute for complex datatypes in ASP.NET Razor MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, attributes

I have a very simple requirement. In MVC4 project I have to show a form with @HTML.labelFor field derives values from attribute fields of a properties of viewmodel class. It works fine for simple properties such as Employee Code how ever it does not work for custom datatypes of person class.

```
namespace MvcApplication1.Models
{
  public class EmployeeViewModel
  {
    [Display(Name = "Employee Code:")]
    public string EmpCode { get; set; }

    public person PersonInfo { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Department Name:")]    
    public string Department { get; set; }
  }
}

namespace MvcApplication1.Models
{
  public class Person
  {
    [Display(Name = "First Name:")]
    public string FName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Last Name:")]
    public string LName { get; set; }
  }
}
```

`@Html.LabelFor(m => Model.EmpCode)` shows label correctly as Employee Code:

`@Html.LabelFor(m => Model.PersonInfo.FName)` shows label incorrectly as FName:

`@Html.LabelFor(m => Model.PersonInfo.LName)` shows label incorrectly as LName:

`@Html.LabelFor(m => Model.PersonInfo.Department)` shows label correctly as Department Name:

I am trying to figure out how do I show attribute information for object type properties. Do I have use extension methods?

Comment: Check the below link. It may help you.

[DisplayName for complex type][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10008768/display-name-for-nested-complex-type

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're using the wrong attribute. This simple example below works.

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new ParentModel {
        Name = "Parent name", 
        Child = new ChildModel {
            Name = "Child name"
        }
    };

    return View(model);
}
```

**Models:**

```
public class ParentModel
    {
        [DisplayName("Parent name:")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public ChildModel Child { get; set; }
    }

    public class ChildModel
    {
        [DisplayName("Child name:")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

**View:**

```
@model ParentModel

@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Child.Name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your person attribute null?

Try adding a default constructor in `EmployeeViewModel` and add

```
PersonInfo = new Person();
```

Comment: Yes I am already instatiating personinfo object in EmployeeViewModel default constructor.